# How to add GeyserMC to my minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I created a minecraft server from scratch without paper or spigot. I need to add geyser, but I don't know how. I've installed geyser.jar. Please tell me how to add Geyser to my Server. Also I need to add Floodgate

Comment: What progress ?

Comment: Are you on bedrock or java? The tags are very confusing.

Comment: @Deer492 geyser allows you to connect to java servers with bedrock, and so his tags are correct.

Comment: @JRBros nvm I got confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you downloaded the Geyser.jar file, first of all, you will not be able to add geyser to the your as you did not make a spigot server, and geyser is a spigot plugin.

First make a spigot server, if you don't know how to do that then look it up on youtube, it is pretty easy (except for the port-forwarding part).

Once you have installed a spigot server, run it once, then let all the folders generate. Then stop the server. Now where the server files are located, there you will be able to see a plugins folder. Simply put the geyser.jar file in the plugins folder. Run your server again, and It should work.

[See this for more in detail clarity of the server installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwTXo-Ig5sc)

Comment: I have geyser standalone. Also I want to add floodgate.

Comment: @JRBros I will see that, but I forgot to include that please download geyser-spigot.jar, if you will create a spigot server

Comment: @JRBros try following this if it helps :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0y0VgoiFAs
Actually, I never personally tried geysermc, so I can't sugest in detail, but I hope this tutorial might help you, sorry for the delay and inconvinience.

Comment: Thank you for the video. It was so helpful :)

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help!

Comment: The video you gave also helped me to join my friend's server through geyser standalone